# Python function pass-in variable to be used as name inside function

Tags: python, dataframe, parameter-passing

I'd like to change column name of dataframe:

```
def test(var):
    dic={'a': [5, 9],
     'b': [4, 1],
     'c': [2, 9]}

    df=pd.DataFrame(dic).transpose()
    df.columns=['aad',var_'k']
    return df
test('lalala')
```

I would like second column name as `var_'k'`; that is, if I passed in `lalala`, the column name should be: `lalala_k`. But obviously there's syntax problem. What should I do?
Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a normal string; you can build it up with concatenation or string functions. For example:

```
col = var + '_k'
```

or

```
col = '{}_k'.format(var)
```